# Переворот словаря Map

Tags: c++, map

Я уже писал вопрос на эту тему, но появилась новая проблема.
Кажется, я делаю что - то не так. Эта программа - задача из практикума. То, что я написал работает правильно, словарь переворачивается.
Вот код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

map<string, string> BuildReversedMap(const map<string, string>& m) {
    //...
    map<string, string> NewMap;
    for(const auto& [key, value]:m)
    {
        NewMap[key] = value;
    }
    return NewMap;
}
map<string, string> g = {{"cat", "felis catus"}, {"dog", "canis lupus"}};
int main()
{
    for(const auto& [key1, value1]: BuildReversedMap(g))
        cout<<"{"s<<value1<<", "<<key1<<"},"s;
    return 0;
}
```

Но в ответ я получаю это:

Задача прошла 2/4 проверок

Возможные проблемы:

- Ваша функция неправильно обращает словарь

Я что - то путаю или дело не в словаре?

Comment: я что-то путаю, или Вы, получив из одного словаря пару (key, value) без изменений записываете ее во второй словарь? Строка `NewMap[key] = value;` не должна выглядеть так: `NewMap[value] = key;`?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, я копирую словарь и вывожу наоборот

Comment: Но Вам же нужно не вывести наоборот, а перевернуть словарь?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, если сделать так, чтобы новый словарь составлялся сразу перевёрнутым, у меня получается неправильный вывод

Comment: Получается вот так: {canis lupus, dog},{felis catus, cat},

Comment: Так сделайте вывод правильным. Переверните словарь, и выводите его в нормальном порядке, а не в перевернутом.

Comment: а должно быть: {felis catus, cat},{canis lupus, dog},

Comment: На сколько понимаю, это уже вопрос сортировки значений в словаре...

Comment: Я всё вывожу в правильном порядке, такое чувство, будто изменилась сортировка и эти пары изменили свой порядок

Comment: std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Словарь упорядочивает пары в порядке ключей, как понимаю. В данном случае - в алфавитном порядке

Comment: Можно полное условие задачи?

Comment: @dIm0n, я разобрался. Оказалось, что нужно было использовать сортировку не по ключу, а по значению

Comment: @МСЧемодан можете дать ответ на собственный вопрос с помощью кнопки ниже (не в вопросе)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

map<string, string> BuildReversedMap(const map<string, string>& m) {
    //...
    map<string, string> NewMap;
    for(const auto& [key, value]:m)
    {
        NewMap[value] = key;
    }
    return NewMap;
}
map<string, string> g = {{"cat", "felis catus"}, {"dog", "canis lupus"}};
int main()
{
    for(const auto& [key1, value1]: BuildReversedMap(g))
        cout<<"{"s<<key1<<", "<<value1<<"},"s;
    return 0;
}
```